# String slicing with reverse indexing

Tags: python, string, slice

I am investigating the slicing of a string with the following code:

```
s='abcdefgh'
print(len(s))
print(s[-1:-9:-1])
print(s[-8])
```

whose output is:

```
8
hgfedcba
a
```

Why when printing reverse we need to slice till -9 while the last character i.e 'a' at -8?

Comment: @matt It is Python :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because how indexing works in Python.

`s[-1: -9: -1]` has 8 characters just like `s` or `s[0: 9: 1]` has 8 characters. The last index is always ignored. This is done so that things like `range(n)` have, like the call suggests, `n` terms although it goes from 0 to `n-1`.

It is clearer if you forget numbers altogether and just look at this object: `s[0: len(s): +1]`. Reverse the sign of the indexes and substract -1 to get the opposite string `s[-0-1: -len(s)-1: -1]`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, slicing can be used to get the sub-section of the Object.

- len(S) - return the length of the string.
- S[index] - get the character at a particular index from the start. positive index.
- S[-index] - get the character at a particular index from the end. negative index.
- S[start:end] - slice the string from a start index to an end position not index.
- S[start:] - slice the string from a start index to the last position.
- S[:end] - slice the string from 0 indexes to the end position.
- S[:] - get the whole string like copy the string.
- S[i:j:k] - slice the string with step. default k is +1. like s[2:10:2]
- s[::-1] - reverse the string.

Comment: Slicing does not include the `end` position (ex. `s="abcd"; s[0:4]` does not include `s[4]`)

Comment: In my answer context, position start from 1 and index starts from 0.